# Why are tooltips appearing on my custom controls?

Tags: .net, vb.net, controls, tooltip

I have a form with some user-defined controls which inherit from Button. When I populate the form and put text on the controls, some (but not all) of them show a tooltip when I hover the mouse over them. The tooltip text is the same as the control's text.

The selection of controls which have this tooltip is the same each time for the same data input. I have not yet managed to check if it is the same selection for different data.

There is a tooltip associated with the form, but its Active property is set to False and the text for the tooltips is always "" at this point of the program. I've tested this.

The form and the program are generated using VS Community 15.9.7.

There is a toolbar with icons which display tooltips, but removing this has no effect, so that's not implicated.

I can't see any .NET documentation which implies that buttons get automatic tooltips.

Code will be difficult - it's a big program and a lot of the form code is auto-generated by VS. I'll try to generate some pseudo-code if it would help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out what's happening. There seems to be an undocumented feature of Button class. When AutoEllipsis is set to True and .NET thinks that some text is missing because the button's too small, it very helpfully gives you an automatic tooltip. This would be fine except for two things:

1. The Tooltip appears even if there's room on the button for the text. This is annoying but sort of OK.
   [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dlav.png)
   [and another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFI15.png)
2. The tooltip appears on top of the tooltip that the programmer assigned to the button. This is a real pain, as in my program this changes depending on the state of the program and has a real meaning.